# How to get a specific User's last Check-in in foursquare?

Tags: api, foursquare

What is the user id? The API doesn't seem to work for anything but self.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/**self**/venuehistory?oauth_token=myToken

My app requires data about the last check-in of some specific(one) user who won't be logged in every instance of the app. Can I replace self with some user id?

Any ideas how should I move forward?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The venuehistory endpoint is only available for `self`, you cannot view an aribtrary user's venue history (not even your friends).

You can see a friend's most recent check-in from the `/users` endpoint, by calling `/users/ID`. Their most recent public check-in will be available in the response of that endpoint.